# Joomla Redirect Manager - Advanced Mode

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I found this option under global configuration. What does turning it on do exactly?

Comment: http://joomla.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can help for SEO purpose.

This option work with the Redirect component (In admin menu "Components > "Redirect"). When you turn on the advanced option it will give the possibility to choose the status of a redirect code. By default the component will give "301 Move Permanently" but by activating the advanced option you will be able to select statues like "307 temporary redirect" or "308 permanent redirect" and my favorite "418 I'm a teapot" ;) .

Simon Kloostra have write a nice article about SEO and redirection : http://joomlaseo.com/checklist/reroute-non-existing-url-s-with-301-redirects

For the "418 I'm a teapot" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper_Text_Coffee_Pot_Control_Protocol

Cya :D

Answer (score 0):

We have written an exhaustive post on the Advanced Mode in Joomla's Redirect Manager. You can find it here: http://www.itoctopus.com/the-advanced-mode-in-joomlas-redirect-manager-a-mystery-unveiled

In essence, it will allow you to set the HTTP status code to something other than 301 (which is the default). It's useful for some people out there, but we typically advise against using the Redirect Manager since it's somehow confusing.